Why do different ways of computing $\langle p^2 \rangle$ require integration by parts to match?
I'm learning the basics of quantum mechanics from Binney and Skinner's book, and I'm trying to do a very basic exercise (2.5d), yet am struggling. The exercise is to calculate $\langle p^2 \rangle$. Super straightforward stuff. Here's why I'm a bit confused: if you apply the definition of the expectation value, you get that
\begin{align*}
\langle p^2 \rangle = \langle \psi | p^2 | \psi \rangle.
\end{align*}
Going a bit further, I wrote down the following calculations.
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi | \hat{p} \circ \hat{p} | \psi \rangle 
& = \langle \psi | \hat{p} \left( \int dx \ |x \rangle \langle x | \hat{p} | \psi \rangle \right)\\\\
& = \langle \psi | \hat{p} \left( \int dx \ |x \rangle \left( -i \hbar \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right) \right)\\\\
& = - i \hbar \langle \psi | \hat{p} \left( \int dx \ |x \rangle \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right)\\\\
& = - i \hbar  \left( \int dx \ \langle \psi | \hat{p} | x \rangle \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right)\\\\
& = - i \hbar  \left( \int dx \ (\langle x | \hat{p} | \psi \rangle)^* \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right)\\\\
& = \hbar^2 \int dx \ \left( \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x} \right)^* \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}.
\end{align*}
If you integrate by parts on the final answer, you can recover the "usual" answer of
\begin{align*}
\langle p^2 \rangle = - \hbar^2 \int dx \ \psi^* \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}.
\end{align*}
My question is this: why do these two methods yield "different" initial answers? Is there anything deeper to this, or is it just a mathematical necessity?

What two methods are you asking about because so far I see only one answer unless the other result is buried in the linked book.

@Triatticus The "usual" method that I'm quoting here is where you just apply the black-box definition of $\langle Q \rangle = \int dx \ \psi^* Q \psi$.

You are more or less assuming $\hat p$ is self-adjoint so that
$$
\langle \psi\vert \hat p^2\vert\psi\rangle= \langle \psi\vert\hat p\hat p\vert\psi\rangle=
\langle \psi\vert \hat p^\dagger \hat p\vert\psi\rangle = \langle \hat p \psi\vert\hat p\psi\rangle
$$
and you technically need integration by parts to move one derivative
in
$$
\int dx \psi^*(x)\frac{d}{dx}\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)
$$
to the left, plus the assumption that the boundary terms disappear (usually $\psi(\pm\infty)=0$) and “smooth enough” functions $\psi(x)$.  Using Dirac notation:
$$
\langle \psi\vert \hat p^\dagger \sim \langle \hat p\psi\vert
$$
so that $\psi(x)^*\frac{d}{dx}\sim \left(\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\right)^*$ using integration by parts,
since the derivative is initially on the right of $\psi^*(x)$.
Doing this will produce something that goes like
$$
\langle\hat p\psi\vert\hat p\psi\rangle=\int dx \left(\frac{d}{dx}
\psi(x)\right)^*  \left(\frac{d}{dx}\psi(x)\right)
$$
when you use coordinates.  Note that I (purposely) left out $i$’s and $-i$’s: you can chase those by yourself.  Finally, the assumptions on $\psi(x)$ are essential here, as are the boundary conditions: see this question or this question for technicalities when the boundary conditions used above are not valid.

I am not sure why you chose to apply it that way. I mean, in particular, why did you not attempt
$$
\begin{align}
\tag1\left<\hat p{}^2\right>
&=\int\left<\psi|x\right>\mathrm dx\left<x|\hat p{}^2|\psi\right>
\end  {align}
$$
so that then you will not require the integration by parts? Anyway, the IbP is a proof of equivalence and so technically you can say that the symmetric version is also the $\hat p{}^2$ if you want.

They aren't different - by utilizing integration by parts, you are explicitly demonstrating that your final and penultimate expressions are equal to one another.

I can see that the final answers are completely equivalent, but I suppose I'm wondering why the former answer required an integration by parts to match the latter. I know that "why questions" like this are sometimes unanswerable (as in, that's just the way it is), but I just wanted to make sure.
